# Co-variance of two random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, uniform-distribution, covariance, binomial-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be jointly distributed random variables such that $Y|X=x \in Bin(n,x)$ with $X \in U(0,1)$. We must find $E(Y)$, $Var(Y)$ and $Cov(X,Y)$.

I was able to complete the first two tasks, but I ran into trouble on the co-variance.

I used the fact: $ Cov(X,Y) = E[ (Y-E(Y))(X-E(X)) ] = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y) $

I know $E(Y) = \frac{n}{2}$ and $E(X) = \frac{1}{2}$ so the second term must be $\frac{n}{4}$. I know the answer is $\frac{n}{12}$ so the first term must come out to be $\frac{n}{3}$. I've tried many eclectic strategies, but nothing worked.

Thank you for your input!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation

Comment: what is "eclectic strategies"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using law of total expectation,
\begin{align}
E[XY] &= E[E[XY|X]] \\
&= E[XE[Y|X]] \\
&= E[X(nX)] \\
&= n E[X^2] \\
&= n \int_0^1 x^2 dx \\
&=\frac{n}{3}
\end{align}

Comment: That makes sense! Though it's not obvious to me how we go from $E[Y|X] \to (nX)$

Comment: $Y|X$ follows binomial distribution with parameter $n$ and $X$ hence the mean is $nX$.

Answer (score 0):

$E(XY)=EE(XY|X)=E(XE(Y|X))=E(X(nX))=nE(X^2)=\dfrac{n}{3}$